# PhpStorm + smarty шаблон произвольного расширения

Tags: php, phpstorm, smarty

Есть проект с шаблонами smarty, но они с расширением .html и шторм не подсвечивает smarty-синтаксис.

В `"Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Template Data Languages"` `smarty` нет, в инъекциях тоже.

Кто сталкивался? Хелп!

P.S. Пока привязал `*.html` к `smarty` в `"Settings -> Editor -> File types"`, но у данного проекта есть и "чистые" html-файлы, переключаться каждый раз не вариант(

Comment: а что за версия шторма у вас? в 10 там всё есть

Comment: Версия шторма 10.0.3

Comment: Никак. Жизнь - боль.
Хорошо что задачка оказалась единичной.